# Ruby multithreading loops

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I'm trying to make a multi-threaded script and i'm stuck with this Thread.join issue:

```
t1 = Thread.new do
  loop do
    puts "Thread 1: #{Time.now}"
    sleep(1)
  end
end

t2 = Thread.new do
  loop do
    puts "Thread 2: #{Time.now}"
    sleep(1)
  end
end

t1.join() # Starts t1 AND t2 TOO
#t2.join Starts t1 AND t1 TOO
```

each thread join start BOTH threads!?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Thread.new` creates a new thread AND runs it. `Thread#join` doesn't start a thread, it merely 'attaches' it to the main thread and continues execution of the main thread when it's done, 'it' being `t1` here.